# Return a pointer in a function

Tags: c

Why do this always returns me a (nil) or NULL pointer? Even when the pointerA isn't a NULL pointer?

```
struct example *doSomething(struct example*, struct example*);
struct example *pointerA;
struct example *pointerB;
...
main(){
    ...
    doSomething(pointerA,pointerB);
    ...
}
struct example* doSomething(struct example *pointerA,struct example *pointerB)
{
    ...
    return pointerA;
}
```

Comment: There is not enough code there for us to help you.  For what it's worth, in the code that *is* there, `pointerA` *is* a null pointer.  Besides that, it's a bit weird to shadow your global variable with a parameter name like that.

Comment: OT: It's '**int** main()' btw!

Comment: @alk, I'd call that on-topic.  The question is tagged C, after all!

Comment: @CarlNorum: Well, I'd accept, if the OP is expecting the answers/comments to circle around the context of the question posed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a little example you might find useful

```
#include <stdio.h>


struct myexample {
    int a;
    int b;
};

typedef struct myexample example;

example  add(example *first, example *second) {
    example retval;
    retval.a = first->a + second->a;
    return retval;
}

int main() {
    example x1,x2,result;
    x1.a=4;
    x2.a=3;
    result=add(&x1,&x2);
    printf("%d", result.a);
    return 0;
}
```

Please note:

- the use of `&` to pass the addresses of structs as parameters to the function
- in the function the use of -> to use a member within a pointed too struct
- the use of "typedef" to avoid having to say "struct myexample" everywhere

Comment: You are correct but you should probably also let him know that he isn't giving us enough information here... If he wants help he needs to show us the error, which we can only speculate with what he presented.

Comment: @nonsensical you are probably right!  I was thinking if the OP is so unable to express the problem then a recap of some basics is the best way to go, for him/her :)

Answer (score 3):

There really is not enough code in your question, but this line

```
doSomething(pointerA,pointerB);
```

can not change `pointerA` in C, no matter what type `pointerA` is. so if you tried to change it inside the function, you shoud either do

```
pointerA = doSomething(pointerA, pointerB);
```

or pass a pointer to the pointer

```
...
    doSomething(&pointerA, pointerB);
...
}
struct example* doSomething(struct example **ppa, struct example *pb)
{
    ...
    *ppa = something;
}
```

I think the main confusion arises from two points:

1. You are shadowing global variable using a function argument with the same name.
2. Maybe you think that changing a pointer in a function changes it's value in the calling code. This is a common confusion in C.